# Remove leading and trailing chacters for hive column

Tags: dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql, hql

I have a hive column which has unknow numbers of leading and trailing double quotes in column.The column has double quotes inside data as well.

For example column looks like this

[image]

I want output like below

[image]

I have written a pyspark code where I can just strip the " and it works,but I want a solution in hql.
I have also tried regexp_replace like

```
regexp_replace(test,'^"|^""|""$|"$', "")
```

but this is kind of hardcoding.
Can someone please provide a generic solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
val df = spark.sql("select '\"\"\"56\"7\"' as test")
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * +--------+
      * |test    |
      * +--------+
      * |"""56"7"|
      * +--------+
      */
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
    spark.sql("select test, regexp_replace(test, '^\"+|\"+$', '') as test_new from table")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------+--------+
      * |test    |test_new|
      * +--------+--------+
      * |"""56"7"|56"7    |
      * +--------+--------+
      */
```

Comment: @Nils, can you please check this solution?

Comment: Thanks Someshwar Kale for you answer.I didnt notice because I got the answer.